# How to use ice-9 atomic boxes with hash-table

Tags: scheme, guile

I have a simple function that I use to cache values. I use a hash table as a cache. The cache will be accessed from different threads and I want to use [atomic boxes](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Atomics.html) for controlling the access from different threads. So far I have this code

```
; Define the local hash table we will use.
(define cache (make-atomic-box (make-hash-table)))

(define-public (make-cache ITEM fv)
  (let ((val (hash-ref (atomic-box-ref cache) ITEM)))
      (if val 
        val
        (begin 
          (hash-set! cache ITEM fv) ;;this where I want to use atomic box update functions
          fv
        ))
  )

)
```

Now, it is not clear to me how to wrap one of the atomic box update functions (`atomic-box-set!`, `atomic-box-swap!` or `atomic-box-compare-and-swap!` ) around the `hash-set` function to add new values to the hash-table.

So how I can use atomic boxes for updating hash-tables?

Answer (score 0):

Since hashes are mutable, you can simply stack the calls to the hash and the box as `(hash-set! (atomic-box-ref cache) ITEM fv)`.

If you were dealing with an immutable value, you'd need to copy the value out (`atomic-box-ref`) and write the processed value in (`atomic-box-set!`) individually. `atomic-box-swap!` combines these two into a single operation.